# Creat a dynamic Loop in VBA with array

Tags: arrays, excel, for-loop, time-series, vba

I want to create a loop for time series in VBA , so that the LINEST would be done in every row, data for LINEST have to be dynamic, e.g.

`=Linest(C6:N6; Q1:AB2; TRUE)` ==> result array of thre

next row `=Linest(C7:N7; Q1:AB2; TRUE)` ==> result array of three

next row `=Linest(C8:N8; Q1:AB2; TRUE)` ==> result array of three etc. so first component is dynamic, second is static)

Any Idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`Linest` is accepting ranges as inputs, so they can be defined dynamically.

```
Set myRange = Range(Cells(myRowCounter, 3),Cells(myRowCounter,14))
```

You may need to replace the commas above with semicolons, depending on your region and language settings.

`myRowCounter` is the variable you increment each time through your loop to go to the next row.  `3` is column `C`.  `14` is column `N`.

```
Linest(myRange; Q1:AB2; TRUE)
```